# Logica con relaciones en tablas con Workbench

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy estudiando relaciones con tablas y se utiliza para ello workbench.
Soy nuevo en esto y no se si estoy en lo correcto con la lógica para realizar las mismas.
Acá dejo un modelo de Medico - Paciente.
Me podrían decir si el enfoque para las relaciones es el correcto?.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]